Shapefile and GeoTIFF do not match
I am trying to match a shapefile with polygons with a GeoTIFF, but I have a slight offset. The shapefile was created manually.
How can I fix this?
I am preparing a dataset for a neural network that contains images of Sentinel and their masks. When these images are overlaid, the masks shift, but when they are opened using ArcMap, they align correctly. This is likely due to the fact that the pixels in the images are rectangular, but when I convert the mask, it is not possible to maintain the rectangular pixel structure.
How can this problem be resolved?

from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
import glob, cv2, os

def shp_tif(shp_name, out_tif_name):
    input_shp = ogr.Open(shp_name)
    source_layer = input_shp.GetLayer()
    defn = source_layer.GetLayerDefn()
    column_names = []
    for n in range(defn.GetFieldCount()):
        fdefn = defn.GetFieldDefn(n)
        column_names.append(fdefn.name)

    output_raster_location = out_tif_name
    

    src_size_images = glob.glob('sentinel_data_2703/images/*.png')
    
    for image in src_size_images:
        
        if shp_name.split('_')[-1][:-4] in image:
            
            
            file_path = f'./{os.path.basename(image)[:-4]}_im.tif'
            dataset = gdal.Open(file_path)
            projection = dataset.GetProjection()
            W_ = dataset.RasterXSize
            H_ = dataset.RasterYSize
            # Получить геотрансформацию (массив из 6 значений) и размеры растра
            geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
            
            break
            
              
    x_res= W_
    y_res = H_
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(output_raster_location,x_res,y_res,1,gdal.GDT_Int32,['COMPRESS=LZW'])
    
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    srse = osr.SpatialReference()
    srse.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    
    target_ds.SetProjection(srse.ExportToWkt())
    band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    target_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-9999)
    band.Fill(-9999)
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, None, None, [1], options = ['ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE' , 'ATTRIBUTE=Class'])
    target_ds = None

shp_tif('20230720T025952_0B78.shp', 'S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20230720T030017_20230720T030042_049501_05F3CC_0B78_COG.tif')


What is the code supposed to do?

The code converts the shapefile into a raster and then I convert this mask into an image in order to feed it into the neural network. However, when superimposed on the original image from the geotiff file, the mask is slightly offset.
